# Disabling TLS1.1, TLS1.2, SSLv2Hello and SSLv3 on a java 7 application

Tags: java, security

My application is running on jdk1.7.0_51. Now that insecurities are identified in SSL and TLS versions, I disabled all of these by providing the command line parameters

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Ddeployment.security.SSLv2Hello=false"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Ddeployment.security.SSLv3=false"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Ddeployment.security.TLSv1=false"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.1=false"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.2=true"
```

Now my application throws the below exception while invoking a remote gateway. Appreciate any suggestions.

```
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:946)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
at org.apache.axis.components.net.JSSESocketFactory.create(JSSESocketFactory.java:186)
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.getSocket(HTTPSender.java:191)
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.writeToSocket(HTTPSender.java:404)
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:138)
at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
```

Comment: So, you disabled SSL, and now you're asking why your program failed an SSL handshake?

Comment: I read through some blogs [this](https://www.siteground.com/blog/goodbye-ssl-version-3/), [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/java_8_will_use_tls) and disabled SSLv3 and SSLv2Hello. I am new to security, in general, and trying to figure out how SSL and TLS fits into the picture.

Comment: It was good of you to disable SSLv2, and SSLv3. I even nowadays recommend that people disable TLSv1. However, you're going to need to make sure that you're still accepting something that both the server and client are able to communicate with each other. Javaa 7 doesn't really have much support for TLSv1.2. You're going to need to provide some more context, when are you seeing that stack trace? Are you requesting are remote resource?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Paypal is disabling SHA1 certificates on its servers and I am using their api to perform transactions. I am not sure where to start- do we have to regenerate keystore entries using SHA256? or The server automatically picks the best available cipher suite that is more secure by when I disable TLS < 1.2 at jvm invocation?